# Fix duplicate entries in customer tables

Tags: database, ce-1.9.0.1

Having a bit of a nightmare trying to fix a messed up **mg_customer_address_entity_varchar** table.
When I exported customers with dataflow from an old store to a new one, I didn't realize that somehow two columns (Shipping Company and Billing Company) had been duplicated several times across multiple customers, seemingly at random.
So now when existing customers place a new order, they are often seeing a wrong company name in their address.
Unfortunately I have no way of knowing which company name actually belongs to which customer.
The only thing I can think of doing is to completely remove all Shipping Company and Billing Company entries from the database.
I am not very good with phpMyadmin and I'm worried about going and manually deleting entries, especially in bulk, as I might accidentally render the whole table useless or cause errors in the admin.
Can anyone suggest a safe way to remove all Shipping Company and Billing Company entries without causing any unwanted behavior? It has to be done in bulk in the database as there are literally hundreds of such duplicate entries, so I can't do it one by one in the admin.
Many thanks for any help!